# Bootstrap validation is not showing the error message for empty input on submit

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

I am trying to add a Bootstrap validation in a form. My expected results is:
When the form is submitted, if "First name" field is empty, the "Please enter a name" message should be displayed below the field, otherwise "Looks good" should be displayed.

I tried it by adding and removing "d-none" class in the javascript, but the problem is "Looks good" is disappearing but "Please enter a name" is not displaying.

```js
// Example starter JavaScript for disabling form submissions if there are invalid fields
  (function () {
    'use strict';
    window.addEventListener('load', function () {
      // Fetch all the forms we want to apply custom Bootstrap validation styles to
      var forms = document.getElementsByClassName('needs-validation');
      // Loop over them and prevent submission
      var validation = Array.prototype.filter.call(forms, function (form) {
        form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
          if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
            event.preventDefault();
            event.stopPropagation();
            var invalidOptions = document.querySelectorAll(".form-control:invalid");

            invalidOptions.forEach(function (element) {
              element.parentNode.childNodes.forEach(function (node) {
                if (node.className == 'valid-feedback') {
                  node.classList.add('d-none');
                }
              });
            });

            var validOptions = document.querySelectorAll(".form-control:valid");
            invalidOptions.forEach(function (element) {
              element.parentNode.childNodes.forEach(function (node) {
                if (node.className == 'invalid-feedback') {
                  node.classList.remove('d-none');

                }

              });
            });

          }
          form.classList.add('was-validated');
        }, false);
      });
    }, false);
  })();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<form class="needs-validation" novalidate>
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
            <label for="validationServer01">First name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control is-valid" id="validationServer01" placeholder="First name" value="Mark"
                required>
            <div class="valid-feedback">Looks good!</div>
            <div class="invalid-feedback d-none">Please enter a name</div>
            
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit form</button>
        </div>
    </div>
 </form>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your js code is Bootstrap will manage the showing & hiding of the `valid-feedback` and `invalid-feedback` depending on whether the content is valid. By manually adding `d-none` to the `invalid-feedback`, it is affecting this behaviour. Simply remove `d-none` from the classes and it works:

```
<label for="validationServer01">First name</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control is-valid" 
       id="validationServer01" placeholder="First name" value="Mark"
    required>
<div class="valid-feedback">Looks good!</div>
<div class="invalid-feedback">Please enter a name</div>  <!-- REMOVE d-none FROM HERE -->
```

Now, when you submit the form, if the name is empty it will show your "Please enter a name" message.

**Working Example:**

```js
// Example starter JavaScript for disabling form submissions if there are invalid fields
  (function () {
    'use strict';
    window.addEventListener('load', function () {
      // Fetch all the forms we want to apply custom Bootstrap validation styles to
      var forms = document.getElementsByClassName('needs-validation');
      // Loop over them and prevent submission
      var validation = Array.prototype.filter.call(forms, function (form) {
        form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
          if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
            event.preventDefault();
            event.stopPropagation();
            var invalidOptions = document.querySelectorAll(".form-control:invalid");

            invalidOptions.forEach(function (element) {
              element.parentNode.childNodes.forEach(function (node) {
                if (node.className == 'valid-feedback') {
                  node.classList.add('d-none');
                }
              });
            });

            var validOptions = document.querySelectorAll(".form-control:valid");
            invalidOptions.forEach(function (element) {
              element.parentNode.childNodes.forEach(function (node) {
                if (node.className == 'invalid-feedback') {
                  node.classList.remove('d-none');

                }

              });
            });

          }
          form.classList.add('was-validated');
        }, false);
      });
    }, false);
  })();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<form class="needs-validation" novalidate>
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
            <label for="validationServer01">First name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control is-valid" id="validationServer01" placeholder="First name" value="Mark"
                required>
            <div class="valid-feedback">Looks good!</div>
            <div class="invalid-feedback">Please enter a name</div>
            
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit form</button>
        </div>
    </div>
 </form>


</body>

</html>
```